# How to call matrix palette API

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es

I want to use matrix palette API(Like OpenGLES1.1 extension API GL_OES_matrix_palette) on mac(XCode), linux(CDT) and windows(VC++).
But, those API was not able to be found.
And I do not want to use shader. (Only fixed functions)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GL_ARB_matrix_palette](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/matrix_palette.txt)
 for OpenGL.

Comment: Oh, I see.
I found glew library. (The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library)
GL_ARB_matrix_palette was defined in it.
Your answer served as a reference.
Thanks!